# wrong encoding in loading yaml file

Tags: python-2.7, ruamel.yaml

I'm using ruaml.yaml version 0.15.74 in python 2.7.13. I have to use this kind of versions due to exogenously given restrictions.

My ulitmate goal is to read a yaml file and select certain parts of it, save it in a pandas data frame and finally write it to a csv file. For this I have the following self-defined 'DoubleMergeKeyEnabler(object)'.

```
import pandas as pd
import ruamel.yaml
import json
import os

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes=True
yaml.width = 100000

class DoubleMergeKeyEnabler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pat = '<<: '  # could be at the root level mapping, so no leading space
        self.r_pat = '[<<, {}]: '   # probably not using sequences as keys
        self.pat_nr = -1

    def convert(self, doc):
        while self.pat in doc:
            self.pat_nr += 1
            doc = doc.replace(self.pat, self.r_pat.format(self.pat_nr), 1)
        return doc

    def revert(self, doc):
        while self.pat_nr >= 0:
            doc = doc.replace(self.r_pat.format(self.pat_nr), self.pat, 1)
            self.pat_nr -= 1
        return doc


dmke = DoubleMergeKeyEnabler()
```

I load the yaml file using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['text1', 'text2'])

 with open ('test.yaml' as f:
     data = yaml.load(f)
```

Then I select a specific part of my yaml file and try to define a `id` to keep track of it (will be the name of the pandas data frame entry name) and store it within the pandas data frame.

```
_item = data.get('items')
for i in range(0, len(_item)):
    if 'representation' in _item[i].keys() and isinstance(_item[i].get('representation'), ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString):
        _id = 'test' + '_' + 'items' + '_' + str(_item[i].get('representation')).replace(" ","_")
        _txt_to_trans = _item[i].get('representation')
        df.loc[_id] = [_txt_to_trans, '']
```

And here is how the yaml file is given. I also can't change this.

```
groups:
  - &group-dp
    title: "Abschätzungen"
    reference: "group-dp"
    required: true
    description: >
    help_text: |


items:
  - type: "Group"
    <<: *group-dp
    visible: true
    multiple: false
    representation: "Abschätzungen"
```

I get the following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-1fa5952ce8cf> in <module>()
----> 1 import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/tmp/py7455hqj''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/tmp/py7455hqj''');exec(compile(__code, '''/home/nicolas/Desktop/test.py''', 'exec'));

/home/nicolas/Desktop/test.py in <module>()
     39 _item = data.get('items')
     40 for i in range(0, len(_item)):
---> 41     if 'representation' in _item[i].keys() and isinstance(_item[i].get('representation'), ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString):
     42         _id = 'test' + '_' + 'items' + '_' + str(_item[i].get('representation')).replace(" ","_")
     43         _txt_to_trans = _item[i].get('representation')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

In [19]:
```

I somehow need to dencode but that doesn't work. How can I solve this? The full test code is shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import ruamel.yaml
import json
import os

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes=True
yaml.width = 100000

class DoubleMergeKeyEnabler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pat = '<<: '  # could be at the root level mapping, so no leading space
        self.r_pat = '[<<, {}]: '   # probably not using sequences as keys
        self.pat_nr = -1

    def convert(self, doc):
        while self.pat in doc:
            self.pat_nr += 1
            doc = doc.replace(self.pat, self.r_pat.format(self.pat_nr), 1)
        return doc

    def revert(self, doc):
        while self.pat_nr >= 0:
            doc = doc.replace(self.r_pat.format(self.pat_nr), self.pat, 1)
            self.pat_nr -= 1
        return doc


dmke = DoubleMergeKeyEnabler()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['text1', 'text2'])

with open ('/home/nicolas/Desktop/test.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

_item = data.get('items')
for i in range(0, len(_item)):
    if 'representation' in _item[i].keys() and isinstance(_item[i].get('representation'), ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString):
        _id = 'test' + '_' + 'items' + '_' + str(_item[i].get('representation')).replace(" ","_")
        _txt_to_trans = _item[i].get('representation')
        df.loc[_id] = [_txt_to_trans, '']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your traceback, the problem is that

```
if 'representation' in _item[i].keys() and isinstance(_item[i].get('representation'), ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString)
```

tests if a string and not Unicode is `in` the keys, therefore Python tries to convert the keys to ASCII strings and fails on the Umlaut. You should test if the Unicode sequence is `in` the keys:

```
if u'representation' in _item[i].keys() and isinstance(_item[i].get(u'representation'), ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString)
```

and refrain from using `str()` casts of Unicode results in the following lines as well.

The following works on 2.7:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import ruamel.yaml
import json
import os

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes=True
yaml.width = 100000

class DoubleMergeKeyEnabler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pat = '<<: '  # could be at the root level mapping, so no leading space
        self.r_pat = '[<<, {}]: '   # probably not using sequences as keys
        self.pat_nr = -1

    def convert(self, doc):
        while self.pat in doc:
            self.pat_nr += 1
            doc = doc.replace(self.pat, self.r_pat.format(self.pat_nr), 1)
        return doc

    def revert(self, doc):
        while self.pat_nr >= 0:
            doc = doc.replace(self.r_pat.format(self.pat_nr), self.pat, 1)
            self.pat_nr -= 1
        return doc


dmke = DoubleMergeKeyEnabler()

data = yaml.load("""\
groups:
  - &group-dp
    title: "Abschätzungen"
    reference: "group-dp"
    required: true
    description: >
    help_text: |


items:
  - type: "Group"
    <<: *group-dp
    visible: true
    multiple: false
    representation: "Abschätzungen"
""")

_item = data.get('items')
for i in range(0, len(_item)):
    if u'representation' in _item[i].keys() and isinstance(_item[i].get(u'representation'), ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString):
        _id = u'test' + u'_' + u'items' + u'_' + unicode(_item[i].get(u'representation')).replace(u" ", u"_")
        _txt_to_trans = _item[i].get(u'representation')
```

So the for loop need some adjustment in several places to keep being Unicode based. You'll have to reinsert the panda's related stuff.

Comment: thanks for your help! that worked. I will remove the trail above